How to use text from clipboard in JavasScript variable
I am trying to use text from clipboard in JavasScript variable. I read lots of articles but nothing worked.
let myText = 'The text from clipboard is: ';
navigator.clipboard.readText()
.then(text => { myText = myText + ' ' + text; });
myText = myText.toUpperCase();
alert(myText); // THE TEXT FROM CLIPBOARD IS: ...

Maybe it is not working because readText() is asynchronous function?
But it looks like there is no synchronous function for pasting from clipboard... and I need to use text from clipboard in lots of code after it is assigned to variable.
